# Android PopupWindow not dismisses

Tags: android, android-popupwindow

I use `PopupWindow` to show menu in `Fragment` and then navigate with `Navigation Compopnent` to another `Fragment`

```
override fun createPopupMenu(popupView: View?) {
    if (popupView == null)
        return
    menuPopup = PopupWindow(context).apply {
        elevation = requireContext().convertDpToPixel(10f).toFloat()
        setBackgroundDrawable(null)
        height = ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT
        width = ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT
        contentView = popupView
        isOutsideTouchable = true
    }
}
```

When I try to close it with `menuPopup.dismiss()`, it is not always work's because internall check of `isShowing()` returns false. But `PopupWindow` visible and closes on touch outside.

Show method is:

```
override fun showMenu() {
    if (::menuPopup.isInitialized) {
        menuPopup.showAsDropDown(
            some_menu_button,
            requireContext().convertDpToPixel(if (requireContext().isRTL()) -185f else 0f),
            requireContext().convertDpToPixel(8f)
        )
    }
}
```